# Is it possible to get the current class instance from a static class method?

Tags: php, class

Such as in this code:

```
class C{

  function static getInstance(){
    // here
  }

}


$c = new c;
print_r(C::getInstance()); // should be $c
```

or at least using

```
print_r($c::getInstance()); // should be $c
```

Comment: Check out the Singleton pattern here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php

Comment: The second example is extremely stupid. The first example is useless as well. You should better describe which problem you'd like to solve instead.

Comment: You could have more instances of C, which one would you like to get then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the wrong way to create a singleton, but you could do this:

```
class C {

  private static $instance;

  public static function getInstance(){
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function __construct() {
    self::$instance = $this;
  }
}

$c = new c;
print_r(C::getInstance()); // should be $c
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this is **not** the way to do it.

**Update:**

A much better approach would be to do the following:

```
class C
{
   private static $instance;

   public static function getInstance()
   {
     if (!is_null(self::$instance)) return self::$instance;
     self::$instance = new self;
     return self::$instance;
   }

   private function __construct()
   {
     // Whatever
   }
}

$c = new C; // This will not work since __construct() is private
$c1 = C::getInstance();
$c2 = C::getInstance();

echo ($c1 == $c2 ? 'yes' : 'no'); // yes
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Care to leave a comment?

Comment: This is exactly what I would come up with as well, though I have no idea for what purpose :-)

Comment: You don't need to call `C::getInstance()`, you can just use `$c` directly. In case there is code between `$c = new c;` and the call of `C::getInstance()` your code won't guarantee that the function returns the same object as in `$c`. So the answer is technically wrong.

Comment: @hakre: is this what's bothering you about the first version of the code? the fact that it's crazy, error prone and is badly designed would go higher on my list :-) Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @hakre: By 'current' I understand the most recent instance, therefore the code is technically correct, in my view.

Answer (score 3):

Ummm... *no*, because by definition, there *is* no current class instance. The method `getInstance()` can be called from anywhere, and no instance of class `C` needs to even exist.

Answer (score 1):

in PHP 5.3 you have some magic methods like `__invoke()` that should do what you want for your singletons.

Read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke

```
<?php
class CallableClass
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
$obj = new CallableClass;
var_dump($obj);
```